# How to check if the button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a colour selector pop over...how can I display `check` when my button is pressed just so that user knows that the button is pressed.

This is the code I'm using

```
class popUpViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.showAnimate()
    ASAP.tag=1
    Soon.tag=2
    Later.tag=3
    Ages.tag=4
    self.check.alpha=0

}


@IBOutlet weak var check: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Ages: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Later: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ASAP: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Soon: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func buttonClicker(sender: UIButton){
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        self.check.alpha=1
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

These are like button which select the colour of priority, I am adding a UIImageView over it...I want a tick which hides and shows when the user taps the button and the tick should only be seen in one box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just say I personally don't like the way you are approaching the issue.

Although your proposed solution would work (see below), a `UIImage` on top of a `UIButton` isn't very elegant... Instead, I'd subclass `UIButton` overriding its `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function to create a fully customized button that would show/hide the "check" mark when users tap on it.
[PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com) can help with that. I highly recommend it.

Now to the answer...

---

You could use the `isHidden` property of the `UIImageView` like so:

```
// Connect the image.
@IBOutlet weak var checkImage: UIImageView!

// When users tap the button...
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    // ... unhide / show the image.
    checkImage.isHidden = !checkImage.isHidden
}
```

(Remember to check the`isHidden` property in the Interface Builder, so the `UIImage` starts hidden.)

You also need to adjust the constraints in the Storyboard so the `UIImageView` has:

- Align Trailing to: button
- Align Center Y to: button (center vertically)
- Height / Width constraints

Like this:

[image: constraints]

The final result (ignore that header, that's just an app I'm working on):

[image: result]

Profit.

(On a side note, in Swift you don't need to use `self` outside of blocks/closures.
That is, you don't need to `self.check.alpha` -- just `check.alpha` will do.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the alpha value I would use the isHidden property of the view to hide and show it.

class popUpViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.showAnimate()
    ASAP.tag=1
    Soon.tag=2
    Later.tag=3
    Ages.tag=4
    self.check.isHidden = true

}


@IBOutlet weak var check: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Ages: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Later: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ASAP: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Soon: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func buttonClicker(sender: UIButton){
    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        self.check.isHidden = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
```